# Binary is not optimized for iPhone 5 error message for Xcode 6.3

Tags: xcode6

I've read a number of similar Q&As regarding this subject but none have provided me with a working solution.

All my images are PNG.

My deployment target is 8.3 for iPhone.

I'm using Xcode 6.3

I am using an image catalog.

[image]

[image]

I've tried using -568h in the image name and tried not using it. I tried changing the filename to "Default-568h@2x.png".

[image]

I've deleted all images from the image catalog and dragged them back in again.

I've created a new launch images catalog.

No mater what I've done, the same error message appears when I attempt to upload to the App Store:

[image]

EDIT:

On the off chance that lacking iPad launch images might have triggered this issue, I also added all launch images for iPad. I also renamed all the image file names, created a new launch image catalog (again) and imported all images. Still getting the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue but not sure on the exact reason behind it.

The Launch Screen File field had LaunchScreen selected.

[image]

The correct selection should have been Main.

[image]

This solved the issue and I was able to submit the app without the error message.